# Global (colour) variables

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine

I've found a [few](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16352/global-variable-node-across-multiple-materials) [questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62471/changing-multiple-colours-at-once/62548) around this already, however none are quite satisfactory IMO.

Basically, my use case is to have

1. several materials on a quick switch panel for a number of objects to select theme variations - that works quite well with a custom operator that assigns the materials when triggered from the panel (if there's a better no-code solution I'm happy to look into that).
2. Those materials share (at least) one (base) colour that's **globally** settable, again e.g. from a panel. Now I could also add custom code for that I guess, updating all nodes for all affected materials when a new selection is picked, however,
3. the global colour value should also ideally be animateable, which is where [the node-group trick doesn't work](https://developer.blender.org/T45376) anymore (if I read that ticket correctly; outside of the shared node group the animation of course works again).

So, is there a better alternative than what I mentioned above already?  I had some trouble putting a colour as an object property - if that *should* actually work maybe you could point me to an example for it.

Comment: The third bullet is a bit unclear. What should be animateable? the global color? If that is the case have you tried to use a driver to update a RGB node that is inside a node group?

Comment: @J.Bakker yes, exactly and while the driver _does_ update the colour inside the node group, the cycles renderer doesn't pick that up when the animation is running. That seems to be a limitation that hasn't been addressed yet as far as I can see from the linked ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start Blender from the console with the '--enable-new-depsgraph' parameter. The Nodegroup will work now.